# Why was the Spam flag declined when the user was blatantly recommending his software of the same name

Tags: discussion

[What does a RED X on a database user mean?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/213013/what-does-a-red-x-on-a-database-user-mean/326500#326500)

I can't see it anymore but I am sure that I had marked [Esrim's](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/272847/eserim) reply as Spam because he/she was recommending software of the same name as his.

I was obviously correct as the answer has been deleted.

Comment: ESRI is an acronym for "Environmental Systems Research Institute" https://www.esri.com/en-us/about/about-esri/company so no connection to the Turkish name "Eserim"

Answer (score 6):

The answer:

[image: deleted answer]

That question has a number of deleted answers, including ones which are just uselessly wrong, of the "I had this problem too" variety, or suggesting how to fix the problem (while not answering the question posed).

This particular answer is *Not An Answer* because it's of the "I had this problem too" variety, without offering any kind of an answer.

> ... the user was blatantly recommending his software of the same name

The *slight* visual similarity between "**Esri**" tools and a user named "**Eserim**" is not enough to justify a [spam flag](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/spam-rude-and-abusive-flags). There is no other (non-public) information available to moderators to indicate the post is spam.

Hence the flag was declined with, "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it".

It would not have been useful as a comment either, so the template comment selected on this occasion was not very helpful.

> I was obviously correct as the answer has been deleted.

It's simply *not an answer*, which would have been the appropriate flag.

I do tend to mark flags of the wrong kind *helpful* even if a different action ends up being taken, but on this occasion, it seems to me there is just no reason for a spam flag and having it declined would be more likely to encourage correct usage of the flag in the future.